# How do I display serialized 'REST Export' with date format rather than timestamp?

Tags: importing-exporting, 8

I am using csv_serialization contrib module to add csv encoding to the core Serialization output formats.

I have a view with a REST export display to allow the download of contact form 'message' entities, and as each contact form might have different fields I must return a (serialized) *Entity* rather than *Fields* (with the option to configure each field's display).

The resulting csv download lists created date as a unix timestamp and I need to format it as a human readable time and date, but as far as I can see the 'REST export' does not go through rendering so I cannot preprocess it in the same way I might with a different type of Views display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with the rows being displayed as entities, you can have a [`hook_views_pre_render(&$views)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/8.2.x) invocation alter the entity field properties before they are used they are rendered out.

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render($view) {

  // Only alter my_view_machine_id view, rest_export display
  if ($view->id() == 'my_view_machine_id' && 
      $view->getDisplay()->definition['id'] == 'rest_export') {
    foreach ($view->result as $row) {
      if (isset($row->_entity->created)) {
        // Alter the entity created property to a readable ISO8601 date
        $row->_entity->created->setValue(date('c', $row->_entity->created->value));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There might be a better part of Views rendering pipeline (e.g. REST views export has some templating system) to place this in, but it still renders out the altered serialized property.